# Retain selected members of json array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to retain selected members of a JSON array of objects. I have the JSON array below;

```
[
    {
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "3",
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        XXX: "5",
        YYY: "6",
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        XXX: "1",
        YYY: "2",
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
]
```

I want to retain XXX and ZZZ members such that the new json array will look like this;

```
[
    {
        XXX: "2",       
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        XXX: "5",       
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        XXX: "1",       
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
]
```

One method to do this is to delete YYY member using delete method below.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
    delete jsonArry[i]['YYY'];
}
```

However, I would prefer to have a function that retain than to delete members. Something like RetainMembers(JsonArr, 'XXX', 'ZZZ') that returns the new json array. How can this be done in Javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Just wrap it in a function.

Comment: You could make a copy of the javascript array and then just run the for loop you listed on the copy.

Comment: @R Dub: Thanks! I think that is a good way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use native `map` function for these kind of problems.

```
var actual = data.map(function (obj) {
   var newObj = {};
   newObj['XXX'] = obj['XXX'];
   newObj['ZZZ'] = obj['ZZZ'];
   return newObj;
});
```

I could do it the way you did it, but I don't like changing actual elements. Better to return a new Object.

Answer (score 1):

**[`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** is there specifically for this:

```
var reduced = original.map(function(_item) {
  return {XXX: _item.XXX, ZZZ: _item.ZZZ}; // leave out YYY
});
```

Comment: Correct answer but I can only mark 1 answer as the correct answer. Sorry.